# php currency conversion rounding errors

Tags: php, math

I have a database which stores currency amounts in GBPs (to two decimal places). Occasionally we get orders in in USD. These are converted prior to storage using an exchange rate of 1.51. The problem is when these figures are retrieved and converted back to the original currency I am encountering small rounding errors. For example...

```
$amount = 100 ///figure in USD
$gbpAmount = number_format((float)($amount/1.51), 2, '.', ''); //// gives GBP figure of 66.23

////Store this in dB then retrive////

$usdAmount = number_format((float)($gbpAmount*1.51), 2, '.', ''); //// gives USD figure of 100.01
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this problem?

Many thanks

Comment: Store them to 4 decimal places, then when you round you're only rounding one hundredth of a penny instead of a whole penny.

Comment: Although this is an option I was hoping to find an alternative solution as changing the way the dB stores the data will require changing the other systems that interact with it....a pretty major under taking.

Comment: If you use VAT, removing and then adding it again you will experience problems unless you store to at least 4 decimal places as well. You should always store prices to more decimal places than you need to avoid rounding errors. Although it's a major undertaking, it's one you should do.

Comment: I think you might be right....oh joy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once faced the same issue. My values where stored in a table.

**So instead of saving 2 decimal, I saved 6 and shows only 2 in the client side**